# Trying to implement Ajax comments in WordPress, getting WP error

Tags: php, ajax, javascript, comments

I'm trying to implement Ajax for my comments in WordPress, using [this tutorial](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/ajax-comments.html). But I'm running into issues when integrating the code from the tutorial into my own pre-built theme. The issue is that I either get a WP error of 'Duplicate comment detected; it looks as though you've already said that!'or a standard 500 error. Here's what I've got:

Here's what my *ajax-comments.js* file looks like:

```
 * Let's begin with validation functions
 */
 jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn, {
    /*
     * check if field value lenth more than 3 symbols ( for name and comment ) 
     */
    validate: function () {
        if (jQuery(this).val().length < 3) {jQuery(this).addClass('error');return false} else {jQuery(this).removeClass('error');return true}
    },
    /*
     * check if email is correct
     * add to your CSS the styles of .error field, for example border-color:red;
     */
    validateEmail: function () {
        var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/,
            emailToValidate = jQuery(this).val();
        if (!emailReg.test( emailToValidate ) || emailToValidate == "") {
            jQuery(this).addClass('error');return false
        } else {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('error');return true
        }
    },
});
 
jQuery(function($){

    /*
     * On comment form submit
     */
    $( '#commentform' ).submit(function(){
    
        // define some vars
        var button = $('#submit'), // submit button
            respond = $('#respond'), // comment form container
            commentlist = $('.comment-list'), // comment list container
            cancelreplylink = $('#cancel-comment-reply-link');
            
        // if user is logged in, do not validate author and email fields
/*
        if( $( '#author' ).length )
            $( '#author' ).validate();
        
        if( $( '#email' ).length )
            $( '#email' ).validateEmail();
*/
            
        // validate comment in any case
        $( '#comment' ).validate();
        
        // if comment form isn't in process, submit it
        if ( !button.hasClass( 'loadingform' ) && !$( '#author' ).hasClass( 'error' ) && !$( '#comment' ).hasClass( 'error' ) ){
            
            // ajax request
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : html5_comment_params.ajaxurl, // admin-ajax.php URL
                data: $(this).serialize() + '&action=ajaxcomments', // send form data + action parameter
                beforeSend: function(xhr){
                    // what to do just after the form has been submitted
                    button.addClass('loadingform').val('Loading...');
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    if( status == 500 ){
                        alert( 'Error while adding comment' );
                    } else if( status == 'timeout' ){
                        alert('Error: Server doesn\'t respond.');
                    } else {
                        // process WordPress errors
                        var wpErrorHtml = request.responseText.split("<p>"),
                            wpErrorStr = wpErrorHtml[1].split("</p>");
                            
                        alert( wpErrorStr[0] );
                    }
                },
                success: function ( addedCommentHTML ) {
                
                    // if this post already has comments
                    if( commentlist.length > 0 ){
                    
                        // if in reply to another comment
                        if( respond.parent().hasClass( 'comment' ) ){
                        
                            // if the other replies exist
                            if( respond.parent().children( '.children' ).length ){  
                                respond.parent().children( '.children' ).append( addedCommentHTML );
                            } else {
                                // if no replies, add <ol class="children">
                                addedCommentHTML = '<ol class="children">' + addedCommentHTML + '</ol>';
                                respond.parent().append( addedCommentHTML );
                            }
                            // close respond form
                            cancelreplylink.trigger("click");
                        } else {
                            // simple comment
                            commentlist.append( addedCommentHTML );
                        }
                    }else{
                        // if no comments yet
                        addedCommentHTML = '<ol class="comment-list">' + addedCommentHTML + '</ol>';
                        respond.before( $(addedCommentHTML) );
                    }
                    // clear textarea field
                    $('#comment').val('');
                },
                complete: function(){
                    // what to do after a comment has been added
                    button.removeClass( 'loadingform' ).val( 'Post Comment' );
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

I've registered and enqueued it in my *functions.php* file, like so:

```
function misha_ajax_comments_scripts() {
 
    // I think jQuery is already included in your theme, check it yourself
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
 
    // just register for now, we will enqueue it below
    wp_register_script( 'ajax_comment', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/ajax-comment.js', array('jquery') );
 
    // let's pass ajaxurl here, you can do it directly in JavaScript but sometimes it can cause problems, so better is PHP
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax_comment', 'html5_comment_params', array(
        'ajaxurl' => site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'
    ) );
 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax_comment' );
}
```

and have also leveraged the custom function that my theme uses for comments (also in *functions.php*):

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajaxcomments', 'html5blankcomments' ); // wp_ajax_{action} for registered user
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxcomments', 'html5blankcomments' ); // wp_ajax_nopriv_{action} for not registered users

// Custom Comments Callback
function html5blankcomments($comment, $args, $depth)
{
    
    $comment = wp_handle_comment_submission( wp_unslash( $_POST ) );
    
    extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
    
    if ( is_wp_error( $comment ) ) {
        $error_data = intval( $comment->get_error_data() );
        if ( ! empty( $error_data ) ) {
            wp_die( '<p>' . $comment->get_error_message() . '</p>', __( 'Comment Submission Failure' ), array( 'response' => $error_data, 'back_link' => true ) );
        } else {
            wp_die( 'Unknown error' );
        }
    }

    if ( 'div' == $args['style'] ) {
        $tag = 'div';
        $add_below = 'comment';
    } else {
        $tag = 'li';
        $add_below = 'div-comment';
    }
    
    /*
     * Set Cookies
     */
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    do_action('set_comment_cookies', $comment, $user);
    
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
?>
    <!-- heads up: starting < for the html tag (li or div) in the next line: -->
    <<?php echo $tag ?> <?php comment_class(empty( $args['has_children'] ) ? '' : 'parent') ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
    <?php if ( 'div' != $args['style'] ) : ?>
    <div id="div-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>" class="comment-body">
    <?php endif; ?>
    
    <div class="comment-author vcard">
    
    <?php printf(__('<cite class="fn">%s</cite><span class="says"> </span'), get_comment_author_link()) ?><a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ) ?>"></a>
    
        <?php
                        printf( _x( '%s ago', '%s = human-readable time difference', 'your-text-domain' ), human_time_diff( get_comment_time( 'U' ), current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) );
                        ?>
    </div>
    

    

    <?php comment_text() ?>
    
    <?php if( get_field('commenter_rating_number', $comment) ): ?>
            
            <span class="commenter-rating"><ion-icon name="star"></ion-icon><?php the_field('commenter_rating_number', $comment); ?></span>
            
        <?php endif; ?>
    
    <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata"><?php edit_comment_link(__('(Edit)'),'  ','' );
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="reply">
    <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array('add_below' => $add_below, 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))) ?>
    </div>
    <?php if ( 'div' != $args['style'] ) : ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="separator"></div>
<?php }
```

Finally, this is the code that outputs it in the theme itself - the comments.php file:

```
<?php comment_form(array(
    'title_reply' => '',
    // Redefine your own textarea (the comment body).
        'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . _x( 'Comments', 'noun' ) . '</label><textarea id="comment" name="comment" aria-required="true" placeholder="What are your thoughts?"></textarea></p>',
)); ?>



<?php if (have_comments()) : ?>

    <h5><?php comments_number(); ?></h5>

    <ul class="comment-list">
        <?php wp_list_comments('type=comment&callback=html5blankcomments'); // Custom callback in functions.php ?>
    </ul>

<?php elseif ( ! comments_open() && ! is_page() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) ) : ?>

    <p><?php _e( 'Comments are closed here.', 'html5blank' ); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Any thoughts? I'm looking at the variables that are being passed and everything seems correct, but with those errors I feel like I might be overlooking something just as simple as that.

Any help is immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Instead of trying to *combine* the two functions together in my functions.php file, I added both of them. Why did this work? Because one is *adding* a new comment (via a call to ajax-comments.php) and the other function is querying all the existing comments. So it's something like this:

1. My original `html5blankcomments()` function grabbed the existing WP comments.
2. the `misha_submit_ajax_comment()` function (that you can see in the tutorial link I posted in my question) talks to the ajax-comments.php file and just works on submitting (and displaying) the **new** comment.
3. With both functions running, we get the old comments (`html5blankcomments()`) and the new comments `misha_submit_ajax_comment()` showing up without page refresh.

Because they both need to exist, combining them was not the answer. I thought it could all happen in one function (and perhaps it *can*), but that was not how the tutorial code was written.